# When downloading windows updates on Windows 8.1 the progress is stuck on 0% downloading

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update

When downloading windows updates on Windows 8.1 the progress stays on 0%.

I have ran the Windows Update troubleshooter and restarted the Windows Update service. However `TiWorker.exe` is running.

Comment: Please provide the appropriate contents from the Windows Update log file.  Microsoft has documented the process to create the appropriate text file

Comment: I used these instructions. https://www.poftut.com/read-filter-windows-update-log-command-line/

Comment: Here's the error log @Ramhound https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2015775

Comment: Your machine is unable to reach Microsoft

Comment: How do I fix it? I disabled my antivirus and firewall and used a working internet connection and it still doesn't work. However I have new errors in my log.

Comment: I have new errors. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2018297

Comment: What you submitted does not contain anything helpful. Your original log information clearly shows your unable to read the Microsoft servers.

Comment: If my computer is unable to reach Microsoft, how do I fix it?

Comment: You have to determine the reason your communication with Microsoft servers have been disrupted.  Have you used any application designed to disable spying features on Windows 8.1?

Comment: LOL No I haven't. I'm downloading Wireshark to see if that helps.