# DISM is taking over 24 hours

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, dism

I'm having problems installing Windows Updates so I thought that if I use DISM and then SFC, that it might fix the problem.

When I run

> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

It takes over 24 hours to complete and the progress stays at 20% for over 24 hours.

How can this be fixed?

My internet connection is working.

Comment: "How can this be fixed?" - You don't;  It sounds like you have a system drive failure, caused by I/O errors, there really isn't anything you can do about that except replace the drive.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Refer to this question. https://superuser.com/q/1586064

Comment: @desbest. - Windows 8.1 also has tracking features, Windows 7 had them has well, instead of submitting commentary edit your question. The command you ran does not require an Internet connection.  **DISM taking 24 hours to complete indicates you have a drive failure.** please replace the drive

Comment: @Ramhound I will be buying a new laptop in October or November so that will give me a new hard drive. But until then, I'm stuck with the laptop I have. I finally managed to get DISM to complete twice, and here's my log. Search for the word error. https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2019802